# Where to declare variable to access from anywhere in program?

Tags: c#

I am making a WinForms application using C#.  I would like to declare a variable to access throughout the program but I do not know where to initialize it?

The program is BStree-based and this is what I am trying to initialize:

```
BSTree<string> record = new BSTree<string>();
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable

Comment: I did this, but I get an build error,
inconsistent accessibility 
for record

Comment: You might just need to explicitly declare that variable as public.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829698/access-textbox-from-anywhere-in-application

Comment: Thanks Everyone, Sepster answered my question and his method worked 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program is trivial - eg just one form and no additional class files etc (eg a simple school assignment), then you'd probably just declare a static global inside your `Form` class but outside any methods, eg

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
   static private BSTree<string> record = new BSTree<string>();

   public MyForm()
   {
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

And then access it from within your `MyForm` instance(s) as eg `MyForm.record`.

Note also that you can just *declare* the variable (eg `static private BSTree<string> record;`) outside the methods, but then *initialise* it (to eg `new BSTree<string>()`) from within eg your constructor.  There's a very subtle difference between the two approaches (ie effects the order in which various members are initialised), but this is rarely of consequence.

Be aware that the `static` member "belongs" to the *class*, and so there's only one "version" of that member.  ie there's not a separate "version" of that member for each *instance* of your class.

But otherwise, you might have a static "configuration" or "globals" class, that contains these values (and perhaps other values read from eg a config file):

```
public static class MyConfig
{
   static public BSTree<string> record = new BSTree<string>();

   ...
}
```

and then you'd access this from within your `MyForm` class like `MyConfig.record`.

Although - ideally you should expose *properties* not *fields*, eg:

```
public static class MyConfig
{
   static private BSTree<string> record = new BSTree<string>();
   static public BSTree<string> Record
   {
       get {return record;}
       set {record = value;}
   }
   ...
}
```

and then you'd access this from within your `MyForm` class like `MyConfig.Record`.  This would give direct access to the underlying `record` member.

But a more robust approach would be to create specific methods that *operate on* the members on behalf of the consumer, rather than just exposing the members directly to the consumer.  That way you can limit the types of operations that are allowed on them, and can expose the results in a specific way etc.  ie you're adding value to the underlying members, rather than just "holding" them.

Comment: @user2154803 My pleasure mate, thanks for the accept.  Please note I updated/corrected my answer with regard to accessing the static member from within your MyForm class.  I had incorrectly stated you'd use `this.record` - but since the member is static, there is no `record` on the `this` instance, rather, the `record` exists on the class itself, eg `MyForm.record`.

Comment: yea, I understood the idea anyway, thanks again -- I got another question that is a hard to explain, if you don't mind please.

Comment: @user2154803 Sorry heading to bed now... it's 3am in Australia ;-) Post it as a new question, you'll get the help you need!  I'll check tomorrow for your questions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class MyStaticBStreeInstance
{
   public static BSTree Instance {get;private set;}
   static MyStaticBStreeInstance()
       {
          Instance = new BSTree<string>();
       }
}
```

and from anywhere , you can access it by using below code

```
 var bstree = MyStaticBStreeInstance.Instance
```